# Using the barlop in R studio

Tags: r

I have an exercise that tells me to do if the lessons are more than 5.0. I must take the students who passed the lessons to do it as bar chart.
[image]

this is the Data_passed image.I want to make students and the grade bar chart

I did that barplot(table(student$d_grade)) but it says me student didn't find.

dataframe :

```
Data_passed <- structure(list(student = c(21118, 21118, 21118, 21118, 21118, 21118), course = c("C2", "C5", "C3", "C1", "C4", "C7"), year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), exam = c("F1", "F1", "F2", "F1", "S1", "S1"), grade = c(7, 7.5, 7.5, 5.8, 8.2, 6.5), d_grade = c("Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Medium", "Very Good", "Good")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
barplot(table(Data_passed[c("student", "d_grade")]))
```

[image]

## data

```
Data_passed <- structure(list(student = c(21118, 21118, 21118, 21118, 21118, 21118), course = c("C2", "C5", "C3", "C1", "C4", "C7"), year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), exam = c("F1", "F1", "F2", "F1", "S1", "S1"), grade = c(7, 7.5, 7.5, 5.8, 8.2, 6.5), d_grade = c("Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Medium", "Very Good", "Good")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Error in df[c("student", "d_grade")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @maikl Please show your data by `dput(df)`

Comment: function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}

Comment: @maikl What's the name of your data? Use `dput` and copy/paste to your post.

Comment: function (x, file = "", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", 
    "niceNames", "showAttributes")) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (nzchar(file)) {
            file <- file(file, "wt")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else file <- stdout()
    .Internal(dput(x, file, .deparseOpts(control)))
}
<bytecode: 0x000001b4e64a3b28>
<environment: namespace:base>

Comment: @maikl No, that's not your data. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/12158757

Comment: @maikl what's the name of your data frame?

Comment: Data_passed  is the dataframe

Comment: @maikl then run `dput(Data_passed)`, and copy/paste the output to your post.

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding I do it. but it was too much so I can't put it all

Comment: @maikl We can use part of it, e.g., `dput(head(Data_passed))`

Comment: structure(list(student = c(21118, 21118, 21118, 21118, 21118, 
21118), course = c("C2", "C5", "C3", "C1", "C4", "C7"), year = c(2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), exam = c("F1", "F1", "F2", "F1", 
"S1", "S1"), grade = c(7, 7.5, 7.5, 5.8, 8.2, 6.5), d_grade = c("Good", 
"Very Good", "Very Good", "Medium", "Very Good", "Good")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))